# How do I get FromCity Name of Call using CallSId

Tags: c#, twilio-api

I want From City,State name of call which are display in call log at https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/logs/calls  Request Inspector. My code is in C#, and I am using Twilio.TwilioRestClient(AccountID,token) to connect API of Twilio

```
CallResult calls = twilio.ListCalls(request);
var inb = (from c in calls.Calls
          where c.Direction.Contains("inbound")
          select c).ToList();

foreach (Call c in inb) {
       IncomingPhoneNumberResult phone = twilio.ListIncomingPhoneNumbers(c.From, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried

Comment: there is no api documentation available?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried, and please give an example of the data you find at that address as we cannot see.

Comment: I have just list of calls CallResult calls = twilio.ListCalls(request);

Comment: I have added sample code to find Resquest details of call.